# Ganiw botnet malware

Tags: malware

I have been notified by my sysadmin that my Ubuntu 16 PC has been infected by a botnet called "Ganiw". Information on the internet is very scarce, could you please give me some advice on how to remove it?

thank you

Comment: Did you get any details on it? This is very unlikely.

Answer (score 4):

Links found on google: a description of it on [Telus security labs](http://telussecuritylabs.com/threats/show/TSL20140620-01) and a in depth analysis on [securelist](https://securelist.com/analysis/publications/64361/versatile-ddos-trojan-for-linux/). That last one is full of hints. The backdoor is described as (from the 1st link) ...

> Backdoor.Linux.Ganiw.A is a Backdoor and Bot agent that targets the Linux platform. The malware contacts a remote server, identifying itself, and sending system information. In addition, it receives control commands to perform various nefarious activities on the infected system. Moreover, the malware has the capabilities to embark on different types of DoS attacks. **To survive a system reboot, it adds an entry to the initialization directory "/etc/init.d".**

From this you can deduct 2 things:

- if it is "Backdoor.Linux.Ganiw.a (cupsdd)": check `/etc/init.d` for a file that does this. "The malware also creates symbolic links to the script in /etc/rc[1-5].1/S97DbSecuritySpt". If it is "Backdoor.Linux.Ganiw.a (cupsddh)" then "it creates the file /tmp/bill.lock, in which it stores the PID of the current process. cupsddh stores system data in the structure g_statBase, which is identical to that used by cupsdd." It also checks for a "/usr/libamplify.so" That files holds a config (and it is not a library) (all of this from the 2nd link).

  So check for those files.(most of this from the 2nd link
- Check your outgoing connections (your router log for instance) on dubious outgoing connections.

I disagree with the other answer: don't let clamav "fix" this... if you do have this on your system reinstall it and restore a backup (and confirm that the backup is clean).  And get a better password than you have now: it HAS your admin password otherwise it could not install in `/etc/`.

Please confirm you do have this backdoor. It would be the 1st time I see someone having one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe clamav will detect and quarantine the malware, since Ganiw has been in the clamav library since circa June 2016: virustotal.com/en/file/69070048be6a27d5c9179f412aea9ef00d10ce8cdd99f881447335e15e464ec7/analysis/

ClamAV can be found for Ubuntu in the apt repository. Run this command in a terminal window to install ClamAV:

```
sudo apt-get install clamav
```

If you want to install clamav daemon "clamd" to operate in the background, you may also want to type:

```
sudo apt-get install clamav-daemon
```

For more info, click on the "Ubuntu" link on this clamav website page: https://www.clamav.net/downloads#otherversions